# How to use Replace function and Like together in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use the "replace" function and "like" together do string searching in Sequelize. I manage to do it separately. My question is how to use the both functions in this scenario?

The findAll as following:

```
const search = '';
const where = {
  [Op.or]: [
    { email: { [Op.like]: `%${search || ''}%` } },
    {
      // Here is the problem vvv
      $col: {
        [Op.like]: Sequelize.where(
          Sequelize.fn('replace', Sequelize.col('phone'), '-', ''),
          `%${search || ''}%`,
        ),
      },
    },
  ],
};

DB.models.User.findAll(where);
```

Result SQL:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users
WHERE email LIKE '%%' 
   OR $col LIKE replace(phone, '-', '') = '%%'
```

expected SQL:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users
WHERE email LIKE '%%' 
   OR replace(phone, '-', '') LIKE '%%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
const search = '';
const where = {
  [Op.or]: [
    { email: { [Op.like]: `%${search || ''}%` } },
    {
      $col: Sequelize.where(
        Sequelize.fn('replace', Sequelize.col('phone'), '-', ''), {
          [Op.like]: `%${search}%`,
        },
      ),
    },
  ]
};
```

To make chained functions try this:

```
const search = '';
const where = {
  [Op.or]: [
    { email: { [Op.like]: `%${search || ''}%` } },
    {
      $col: Sequelize.where(
        Sequelize.fn('replace', 
          Sequelize.fn('replace', 
            Sequelize.col('phone'), 
            '-', ''), 
          '.', ''), 
        {
          [Op.like]: `%${search}%`,
        },
      ),
    },
  ]
};
```